# How to print a PDF, displayed with pdf-tools, from Emacs?

Tags: pdf-tools, print

I'm using PDF-Tools (https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools) to display PDFs inside Emacs. But how to print them? C-c C-p raises the question »Print with:« and I have no idea how to answer it.

I'm looking for a solution to print the pdf, not the buffer, if this makes a difference.

My PC is inside a LAN and there are several printers available. I'm on Linux (openSuse Tumbleweed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to set the variable `pdf-misc-print-programm` and possibly also `pdf-misc-print-programm-args` in the `pdf-misc` customisation group. They should be set to the system command that you will print your document with, and that program must be installed on your system.

I use `lpr`, with the settings:

```
'(pdf-misc-print-programm "/usr/bin/lpr") 
'(pdf-misc-print-programm-args (quote ("-o media=Letter" "-o fitplot")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`Print with:` asks you for a command to print with.  In most Linux distros you could use `lp` or `lpr` command to send files to printer.  More about `lp`: http://linux.die.net/man/1/lp